# How to disable/enable the sleep mode programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have an app that must stay awake until the end of a countdown but it will go into 'sleep mode' whenever it reaches the allocated time to sleep.

In my app, I have the option to postpone sleep, so users can disable/enable it.

How do I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 392, accepted):

You can disable the idle timer as follows;

In Objective-C:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

In Swift:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

In Swift 3.0 & Swift 4.0:

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

Set it back to `NO` or `false` to re-enable sleep mode.

For example, if you need it until you leave the view you can set it back by overriding the viewWillDisappear:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
}
```

More about [UIApplication Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/idleTimerDisabled).

Comment: @Gati I doubt it, but I can't confirm since I don't have a watch

Comment: @jrturton Hmm.. It is not working in apple watch. If you got any solution for this then please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for this information.  It will come in handy.  I was wondering if disabling sleep mode in one app will affect the entire device.  Like if I disable it in my app and then exit the app, will it still be disabled after the app exits?  Do I need to check whether it's active or not, and then reenable it on the way out?

Comment: @ScottKilbourn it only affects your app. `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` refers to _your_ app's UIApplication object only.

Answer (score 25):

In Swift 3, to disable the idle timer it is now:

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

To turn the idle timer back on it is simply:

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
```

Additionally, note that `YES` and `NO` are not available in Swift and that you must use either `true` or `false` (as opposed to the previous answer).

Answer (score 4):

**iOS 13, Swift 5,5.1+** to disable the idle timer. In `SceneDelegate.swift`.

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
     UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
 }
```