# iPad app crash making executeFetchRequest:error: and device is in low power consumption

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data

I'm having this problem, I'm making a request with ASIHttpRequest that takes a few minutes, when request is finished the iPad is in low power consumption, the screen is black, etc. The downloaded data is saved in coredata and in this process the app crash.

This is part of the crash information:

```
MyApp[2978] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1f841ec0> identifier: Suspending process: MyApp[2978] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:26 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 10.220 (user 10.220, system 0.000), 51% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 9.860, 49% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6ae39c pread + 20
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3c3b75c8 0x3c3b2000 + 21960
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3c3ca0fe 0x3c3b2000 + 98558
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3c3c929a 0x3c3b2000 + 94874
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3c3e208e 0x3c3b2000 + 196750
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3c3e32be 0x3c3b2000 + 201406
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3c3df488 0x3c3b2000 + 185480
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3c3d8482 sqlite3_step + 2138
8   CoreData                        0x340e596a _execute + 122
9   CoreData                        0x340e5864 -[NSSQLiteConnection execute] + 2168
10  CoreData                        0x341a5486 newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 1006
11  CoreData                        0x340ec73a -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 678
12  CoreData                        0x340ec200 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 464
13  CoreData                        0x340eb618 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 1640
14  CoreData                        0x340e9f12 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 642
15  Georeporting                    0x000b7506 +[Model loadObject:withId:createNew:] (ModelObject.m:51)
16  Georeporting                    0x000b18ae -[Data request:didFinished:] (DataManager.m:309)
17  Georeporting                    0x000a69fe -[Server requestFinished:] (ServerClient.m:80)
18  Georeporting                    0x000e6c04 -[ASIHTTPRequest reportFinished] + 76
```

This is the code of the executeFetchRequest

```
NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[objectClass entityName] inManagedObjectContext:[Model manageObjectContext]];
    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@='%@'", [objectClass primaryKeyFieldName], objectKey];
    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:query];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSArray * objects = [[ModelObject manageObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Comment: First, ASIHTTPRequest was discontinued a long time ago. I would suggest switching over to AFNetworking instead. Second, the problem lies in your sql query here, so why don't you post that?

Comment: ok, i put the code, i use ASIHTTP because i start his project a few months ago and any change is a problem right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the idle timer on iOS extremely easily - see this question:

[How to disable/enable the sleep mode programmatically in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661004/how-to-disable-enable-the-sleep-mode-programmatically-in-ios)

Although that should fix your problem, do make sure that you're not doing your network operations on the main thread. I can't tell from the stack trace you've posted, but I suspect you might be. As someone else has already suggested, you should migrate away from `ASIHTTPRequest` to a more modern alternative if possible.

Comment: If it works for you do mark this answer as correct - it will help other people who come here with the same problem looking for help.