# keep screen active with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a part of my app, where the user will go to a text screen, and while the user is on that page, I want the device screen not to turn off, but to keep it on, and if the user leaves this page, this function be deactivated. How can I do this with flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option A: Use a package

I would use a package for what you are trying to accomplish such as:

- Wakelock: https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock

## Option B: Write platform specific code

If you don't want to use a package, you should investigate how this functionality can be implemented on Android and iOS in native code. Such as:

- Android: [How do I prevent an Android device from going to sleep programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/how-do-i-prevent-an-android-device-from-going-to-sleep-programmatically)
- iOS: [How to disable/enable the sleep mode programmatically in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661004/how-to-disable-enable-the-sleep-mode-programmatically-in-ios)

Then you should refer to the Flutter documentation for writing code towards specific platforms and integrate it into your codebase: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: thank you very much, for the examples I saw in the Flutter package, it will solve my problem! :D